# How to write to iOS or Android simultor to replicate Xamarin's Application.Current.Properties?

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, appium, ios-simulator

I am writing a series of mobile automation tests using Appium to test our Xamarin application.  The tests run on iOS simulators and Android emulators.  The app writes various pieces of data using Xamarin's `Application.Current.Properties` method.  I am trying to determine where on each device this data is written to, and if possible write that data myself using the terminal so I can mock the user being in certain states to speed up my tests.  Thank you!

Comment: the file is `PropertyStore.forms`

Comment: You might want to look at how Microsoft tests this by providing a  `MockDeserializer`  instead of trying to serialize/deserialize the `PropertyStore.forms`  file itself. : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/809e75547cec1a4c84a2eabdcfddb4b4f43fccd5/Xamarin.Forms.Core.UnitTests/MockPlatformServices.cs#L225